# input type = number validation in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to validate `< input type = number >` by using input [number]
directive of module ng of angularjs.

When using an input of type number, with the max (or min) attribute set to number such as

`<input type=number min="20" max="40">`

it works fine , but I my min and max data are coming data dynamically using ng-repeat such as

`<input type=number min="configRow.valueStart" max="configRow.valueEnd">` ,
 then it is not working .

I know that min and max only accept number and I am not much good in writing directives for that , Please help me any such directory or any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

Comment: There's a [fix](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/e1bf206fff36a12b4e5851972d2f28e5cf9695b1) for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`min` and `max` are expecting a value.  So, this should work:

```
<input type=number min="{{configRow.valueStart}}" max="{{configRow.valueEnd}}">
```

Here is a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/lPJhj6?p=preview) showing a demo.  (this is just a modification of the documentation demo).

At the moment, the source for these attributes looks like below.  So, you can see that a value is expected that is then cast to a float with `parseFloat`.  So interpolating the model property `{{}}` to a value is required.

**src/ng/directive/input.js**

```
if (attr.min) {
        var minValidator = function(value) {
          var min = parseFloat(attr.min);
          return validate(ctrl, 'min', ctrl.$isEmpty(value) || value >= min, value);
        };

        ctrl.$parsers.push(minValidator);
        ctrl.$formatters.push(minValidator);
      }

      if (attr.max) {
        var maxValidator = function(value) {
          var max = parseFloat(attr.max);
          return validate(ctrl, 'max', ctrl.$isEmpty(value) || value <= max, value);
        };

        ctrl.$parsers.push(maxValidator);
        ctrl.$formatters.push(maxValidator);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Max length will not work with `<input type="number"` the best way i know is to use oninput event to limit the maxlength, its a generic solution work with all the Javascript framework. Please see the below code.

```
<input name="somename"
    oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);"
    type = "number"
    maxlength = "6"
 />T
```